# Who send the message in android framework?

Tags: android, frameworks, display

In the Android framework, I print a function strack trace. How could I understand who send this message? I need to know who call the function "onHotplug".

```
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1841)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter.printCallStack(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:1336)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter$LocalDisplayEventListener.onHotplug(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:1345)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter$ProxyDisplayEventReceiver.**onHotplug**(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:1317)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.**dispatchHotplug**(DisplayEventReceiver.java:301)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
12-15 18:24:53.009   646   670 I StackTrace: com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

I don't know how can i get the message information.

Comment: The key is the 3rd line from the bottom of the stacktrace you posted: [Looper.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java) is the **receiver** of the message. To figure out **who put it in the queue,** you may want to start with [Intro to Loopers and Handlers](https://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/)

Comment: TLDR; search for `.post(` or `.postDelayed(` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this helps you or not but up to my knowledge
super.onCreate(icicle);
This method is invoked when the activity is started in mobile application